# Is it possible to burn stacked production on industry conversion?

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

The Automatons' racial ability of stacked production lets them store up to 5 turns' worth (7, with research) of production on a system without having it go to waste. This is in addition to the standard 1 turn of overproduction that any race can hold.

In most contexts in Endless Space, you can inefficiently convert industry into science or dust at a 33% conversion rate. Although this "wastes" a lot of potential, it can give you a momentary boost to dust or science, which can be tremendously useful when you're on a tight turn clock to get something done, e.g. during a war.

By default, if you have stacked production as the Automatons, and you choose to convert industry into dust or science, it'll only burn what you produce that turn. Is there any way to tell the game to sell off your stacked production and convert it into dust or science?

Even in our relatively primitive culture on Earth you see this kind of thing happen: stacked production could be something like spare parts, sheets of steel, oil or coal, etc. These things can quite easily be converted into "dust" (money) by simply selling them off. To convert them into science requires a bit more creative thinking, but one way I can envision to do that would be the case of, for example, the Manhattan Project, where many giant expensive magnets had to be purchased to build calutrons for uranium enrichment. Science experiments often do need "industrial" resources to build, as well; take the LHC for instance, which is a marvel of civil engineering as much as it is a marvel of science.

Would be great if you could take stacked production from Automatons' worlds and sell it off for a quick burst of dust in a sticky situation (to support a diplomatic negotiation with dust to sweeten the pot, for instance).

Comment: Don't think it is possible but if your on Steam, you should ask that guy on the forum, he knows everything about the game: https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198053874177

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible :(. You are well researched on how the ability functions.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail? If it's not possible why is it not possible?

Comment: And sourcing your answer is also nice. Add links to other sites (pref a wiki or official documentation).